# PostGreSQL - Controlling transactions

Tags: postgresql, error-handling, transactions

I have a Stored Procedure that in turns calls several other Stored Procedures; each of them returns true or false and internally deal with errors by store them into a table.

Something like this:

```
-- (MAIN STORED PROCEDURE)
BEGIN
 CALL STORED_PROC_1('WW','TT','FF',result);
 IF result = TRUE then
    CALL STORED_PROC_2('a','b','c',result);
    ...
 END IF;
END;

IF result != TRUE THEN
 ROLLBACK;
ELSE
 COMMIT;
END IF;

-- (END MAIN STORED PROCEDURE)

-------
--Example of Stored Procedure 1
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE STORED_PROC_1 (IN a TEXT, IN b TEXT, IN c TEXT, INOUT result boolean)
AS $BODY$
BEGIN

 -- DO SOME STUFF HERE

 IF ERROR_FOUND THEN
   INSERT INTO ERROR_LOG VALUES ('Error','Type of Error',CURRENT_DATE);
   --COMMIT; (I cannot do this commit here but I would like to save the information going into the ERROR_LOG table)
   result := FALSE;
 ELSE
   result := TRUE;
 END IF;
END;
$BODY$;
```

This is actually what I want; only commit if all return TRUE;
The problem is that inside the STORED_PROC_1 or _2 there are error handlings that write into a Error Log table and ... if there are errors, they will return FALSE in the result and, that in turn will call a rollback and I will loose my Error Log.

Is there a way to create a sort of a memory table that I can load with the error info and write it after the ROLLBACK? Or is there a better way to achieve this?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `FUNCTION`s rather than `PROCEDURE`s if you can for all of this because they have transaction control built-in in a sense. If the `FUNCTION` fails you automatically rollback its trasaction.

That being said, instead of doing the insert directly I would make a function like the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func_logerror(error TEXT, errortype TEXT, date DATE DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE)
RETURNS SETOF ERROR_LOG
AS $$
DECLARE
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY
    INSERT INTO ERROR_LOG VALUES (error, errortype, date) RETURNING *;
END;
$$;
```

Call it using either `SELECT` or `PERFORM` depending on whether or not you want the results in the calling function.

```
PERFORM * FROM func_logerror('Error', 'Type of Error', CURRENT_DATE);
```

---

After reading your answer response I've come up with this to help clarify. I was suggesting not using stored procedures at all. Instead handle your error cases in a different manner:

```
-- (MAIN STORED PROCEDURE)
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FUNC_MAIN()
RETURNS boolean
AS $$
DECLARE
    res    boolean;
BEGIN
    SELECT * INTO res FROM FUNC_1('WW','TT','FF');
    IF res = TRUE
    THEN
        SELECT * INTO res FROM FUNC_2('a','b','c');
        ...
    ELSE
        RETURN FALSE;
    END IF;
    RETURN res;
END;
$$;
-- (END MAIN STORED PROCEDURE)

-------
--Example of Stored Procedure 1
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FUNC_1 (a TEXT, b TEXT, c TEXT)
RETURNS boolean
AS $$
DECLARE
BEGIN
    -- ****complete data validation before writing to tables****
    -- If you hit any invalid data return out of the function before writing any persistent data
    -- Ex:
    IF COALESCE(a, '') = '' -- could be anything that may produce ERROR_FOUND from your example
    THEN
        RAISE WARNING 'FUNC_1 | param: a: must have a value'; 
        PERFORM * FROM "Schema".func_errlog('Error','Type of Error',CURRENT_DATE);
        RETURN FALSE;
    END IF;

    RETURN TRUE; -- If you've made it to the end of the function there should be no errors
END;
$$;
```

Comment: Ok, I do have a `PROCEDURE` to do the logs. So instead of doing the `procedure` if I use a `function` to create the logs it will do the `commit` inside the function? And I can control the rest of the procedures with a last commit or rollback but by using functions control the commit of THAT specific function(s)?

Comment: First question, yes. Each function will commit upon completion or rollback upon error. You cannot call `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK` within functions, it's done automatically based on those conditions. I'm not sure I follow the second question. Just know that `PROCEDURE` didn't even exist prior to Postgres 11 if my memory serves correct. It was `FUNCTIONS` before that and I have not found a case yet where I've needed a `PROCEDURE` instead of a `FUNCTION`.

Comment: Also, you can use the `FOUND` environment variable instead of a boolean result to determine whether a function completed or not. I'll add an example to the call in my answer. `FOUND` is set to true if results are returned from the previous query, false otherwise.